# rails app use postgresql shows PG::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I just started a new rails app using

```
rails new myapp --database=postgresql
```

Then I generate some static pages:

```
rails g controller StaticPages home about
```

When I started the server and visit localhost:3000/static_pages/home, the PG::Error shows up:

```
PG::Error

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I didn't change anything else

Any idea how to make postgresql work?

Comment: Your PostgreSQL server appears to be down or listening on some other port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your postgres server is not running. Have you started it up? If you check your system processes do you see the postgres daemon running?

If you are trying to use rails + postgres, I would recommend checking out [this great video by Pete Cooper.](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-and-use-postgres-on-os-x-for-ruby-and-rails-development-4999.html)

Comment: yeah I didn't see it running. Any idea how to start it? Thanks for the video BTW, great resource. But I'm using windows now

Comment: How you start it depends on how you installed it, but you could start by looking for a Windows server to start.